# string.Replace() searching for string + ANY CHAR + string

Tags: c#, regex, json, string

I'm searching a giant .json file, and trying to replace text. Here is the exact situation i'm working with.

```
string json = (a json file string of text)
string result = null;
result = json.Replace("\"$id\":\"7\",\"QuestionNumber", "REPLACMENT TEXT");
```

I want to search the whole json file and replace every occurance with REPLACMENT TEXT. However, I want to search the whole file for

```
"\"$id\":\"7\",\"QuestionNumber"
```

Where, instead of just the number "7", it can be any number. I know I need to use regex but i'm new with regex and i'm not sure how I would go about passing the regex stuff into the string.Replace parameters.

ALSO a major caveat here, is I need to also add "7", but whatever number that happens to be per replacement, into the "REPLACEMENT TEXT" string.

Comment: use a Regex, there is a Regex.Replace method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: instead of the number 7 you can use  `(-??\d*\.\d*)`  <- This should get any number even decimals and negatives. For only integers just use `\d*`

 here is a good reference for [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is this json structured at all... perhaps bringing into a C# object and using LINQ on it would be easier, and faster.

Comment: ok so i want any positive integer. but i also need to save whatever the ANY POSITIVE INT is, so that i can put it into the replacement text. how would i do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Regex.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
//using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex regex = new Regex("\"\\$id\":\"(\\d+)\",\"QuestionNumber");
string result = regex.Replace(json, "REPLACEMENT TEXT $1");
```

This should turn text such as

```
"$id":"8","QuestionNumber
"$id":"3","QuestionNumber
```

into

```
REPLACEMENT TEXT 8
REPLACEMENT TEXT 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think this is exactly what i'm looking for, but i'm getting an unrecognized escape sequence error on the 'd' in (\d). i tried putting (\\d) instead but i don't think that worked..

Comment: Oh yeah oops... is should be `\\d`. That should work though. Try it again.

Comment: still not working, but i'll keep monkeying around a bit. thanks for the help. just to be sure, the (\\d+) is supposed to be a part of the string passed into the regex object, correct?

Comment: @kdeez The (\\d+) is the captured group, which means that in the replacement text `$1` will be replaced with it.

Comment: could it be that the '$' before "id" in the regex string is throwing stuff off? I actually want to include the $ character in the search string. so i'm looking for text "$id.......", not just "id....."

Comment: @kdeez I'll get C# open and test it. I'll update my answer in a bit when I figure out what's wrong. I guess this is what I get for answering without testing first... sorry about that

Comment: hey man, no worries. i appreciate all the help. and i just figured out that i'm pretty sure the $ character is throwing stuff off. but i can't escape out of it with '\', i get an unrecognized escape sequence error. SO. I guess the question now becomes, how to include $ in the regex search.

Comment: @kdeez I just tested, and the current answer should be correct. I just needed to escape the `$` by writing `\\$`.

Comment: Got it working!! hell yeah. thanks again for all the help, i really appreciate it. saved me a bunch of headache!